# How to fix the method in the type Main is not applicable for the arguments ()

Tags: java

So this is my code, I'm trying to figure out a way to get rid of this error:

> The method displayOutput(inputPlayerName, inputStrength, inputAgility, inputIntelligence) in the type Main is not applicable for the arguments ()

I have tried experimenting but still no luck.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        inputPlayerName();
        inputStrength();
        inputAgility();
        inputIntelligence();
        displayOutput();
    }

    static void inputPlayerName() {
        inputPlayerName iPN = new inputPlayerName();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Name of the Adventurer: " );
        iPN.setName(sc.nextLine()); 
        System.out.println("Welcome! " + iPN.getName());        
    }
    
    static void inputStrength() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        inputStrength iS = new inputStrength();
        
        System.out.println("Set your 'Strength' attribute. Maximum of 5 points each. You have  15 points left ");
        iS.setStr(scan.nextInt());
        System.out.println(" Strength :" + iS.getStr());
        
        while (iS.getStr() > 5) {
            System.out.println(" Maximum is 5. Please enter value (1-5) ");
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Set your 'Strength' attribute. Maximum of 5 points each. You have  15 points left ");
            iS.setStr(scan.nextInt());
            System.out.println(" Strength : " + iS.getStr());
        }
    }
    
    static void inputAgility() {
        Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);
            inputAgility iA = new inputAgility();
            
            System.out.println(" Set your 'Agility' attribute. Maximum of 5 points each. You have  15 points left ");
            iA.setStr(scan1.nextInt());
            System.out.println(" Agility :" + iA.getAgi());
            
            while (iA.getAgi() > 5) {
                System.out.println("Maximum is 5. Please enter value (1-5 ");
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("Set your 'Agility' attribute. Maximum of 5 points each. You have  15 points left ");
                iA.setStr(scan1.nextInt());
                System.out.println(" Agility : " + iA.getAgi());
            }
     }
     
    static void inputIntelligence() {
        Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        inputIntelligence iI = new inputIntelligence();

        System.out.println("Set your 'Intelligence' attribute. Maximum of 5 points each. You have  15 points left ");
        iI.setInt(scan2.nextInt());
        System.out.println(" Intelligence :" + iI.getInt());

        while (iI.getInt() > 5) {
            System.out.println("Text color: Red Maximum is 5. Please enter value (1-5 ");
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Set your 'Strength' attribute. Maximum of 5 points each. You have  15 points left ");
            iI.setInt(scan2.nextInt());
            System.out.println(" Intelligence : " + iI.getInt());
        }
    }
     
    private static void displayOutput (inputPlayerName iPN, inputStrength iS,inputAgility iA,inputIntelligence iI) {
        System.out.println("_____________________________________________________________________");
        System.out.println("Congratulations! You have created a new Adventurer");

        System.out.println("Adventurer name : " + iPN.getName());
        System.out.println("Strength : " + iS.getStr());
        System.out.println("Agility : " + iA.getAgi());
        System.out.println("Intelligence : " + iI.getInt());
    }    
}
```

Comment: The information is all there in the exception. Your method `displayOutput()` requires the parameters `(inputPlayerName iPN, inputStrength iS,inputAgility iA,inputIntelligence iI)`. But when you call the method in your `main`, you don't provide these parameters.

Comment: Additionally, class names are supposed to start uppercase.

Comment: So should I just put )inputPlayerName iPN, inputStrength iS,inputAgility iA,inputIntelligence iI) on my Main method?

Comment: After putting `(inputPlayerName iPN, inputStrength iS,inputAgility iA,inputIntelligence iI)` inside main method I get these error

Error: Main method not found in class Main, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the arguments to the displayOutput method. Try to make the functions to return the specific objects and after that pass it to the displayOuput.

Comment: Im Sorry for being noob but, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You fix this error by retrieving your generated objects and then finally passing them to the `displayOutput()` method. Kind of like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    InputPlayerName iPn = getInputPlayerName();
    InputStrength iStr = getInputStrength();
    InputAgility iAgil = getInputAgility();
    InputIntelligence iIntel = getIinputIntelligence();
    displayOutput(iPn, iStr, iAgil, iIntel);
}
```

I altered your method names a bit, to reflect what they actually do.

But overall, I think your approach is too complicated.
It is probably redundant to create classes for each of these values, if they only represent one "stat". What would probably be better to maintain is something like this:

```
public class Player {

    private String name;
    private int strength;
    private int agility;
    private int intelligence;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Player p = new Player();
        p.initName();
        p.initStrength();
        p.initAgility();
        p.initIntel();
        p.displayOutput();
    }

    private void initIntel() {
        // input logic for the intelligence here
    }

    private void initAgility() {
        // input logic for the agility here
    }

    private void initStrength() {
        // input logic for the strength here
    }

    private void initName() {
        // input logic for the name here
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Name of the Adventurer: " );
        name = sc.nextLine(); 
        System.out.println("Welcome! " + name);
    }

    private void displayOutput() {
        // display the attributes here
    }
}
```

But in the end it's up to you what you prefer. You just need to make sure to save your retrieved values accordingly.